Where does Helgason discuss Cartan decompositions of types AI, AII, and AIII?
In the paper "Quantum symmetries and Cartan decompositions in arbitrary dimensions,"
Domenico D'Alessandro and Francesca Albertini refer to Helgason's textbook "Differential geometry, Lie groups, and symmetric spaces" as the authoritative reference on Cartan decompositions. Specifically, the authors reference Helgason's textbook when claiming that up to conjugacy, there exist only three types of Cartan decompositions for su(2): types AI, AII, and AIII.
Is anyone familiar enough with Helgason's textbook to point me towards the exact section in which the aforementioned decompositions are discussed?
I've been thumbing through the book for a while with no success.

It is this paper, and it is for $\mathfrak{su}(n)$, for all $n\ge 2$.

I believe that they may be referring to section X.2.3 "The Involutive Automorphisms of the Classical Compact Lie Algebras" which is actually about the classification of involutions up to conjugacy.
